# Phaser3 sprite animation: loop starting at frame N?

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework, sprite-sheet

In Phaser v3, is it possible to create an animation that loops, but loops from a particular frame rather than starting over at frame 0?

For example: imagine a 30 frame animation. The first 10 frames are the "setup," and then frames 11-30 loop.

Is it possible to configure this so that the animation runs the frames like so:

```
1, 2, ..., 9, 10, 11, 12, ... 29, 30, 11, 12, ..., 29, 30, 11, 12, ...
```

(Note how after frame 30, it starts playing frame 11)

If it's not possible to configure an animation to behave this way, is there a recommended way to make the animation work this way in JavaScript?

One idea is to use the `SPRITE_ANIMATION_COMPLETE` event to detect when the animation ends, and then kick off a new one starting at frame 11, but I'd prefer a declarative approach if possible.

Comment: Just so you know, the official Phaser forum is [https://phaser.discourse.group](https://phaser.discourse.group). Asking on StackOverflow may not give you as good of answers as over on its dedicated forum.

Comment: Oh, nice! I didn't know it had an official forum. I'll go check that out. Thanks a ton @NateLevin